# How can I detect in web page if a Chrome Extension has been enabled (after having been disabled)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want detect in my web page if a Chrome Extension has been enabled(after having been disabled or opposite.

I want to know a chrome extension's enable/disable state in my web page.

I'm sorry about that I do not speak English well.
But I sure would like to know the answer to this question.
Thank you.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752508/detect-if-extension-is-enabled-on-chrome-browser and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752508/detect-if-extension-is-enabled-on-chrome-browser - do they help?

Answer (score 0):

The only chrome API that comes close is `chrome.management` but it doesn't call [onEnabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onEnabled) event listener for your own extension and, anyway, you can't use it from a web page.

So here's a workaround.

On your page send a custom event periodically:

```
var extensionIsEnabled = false;
var messageTimeout;

function pingExtension() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("pingMyExtension", {detail: "hello there"}));
    messageTimeout = setTimeout(function() { extensionIsEnabled = false; }, 1000);
}

document.addEventListener("pingbackFromMyExtension", function(e) {
    clearTimeout(messageTimeout);
    extensionIsEnabled = true;
    console.log("extension is alive!", e);
}

setInterval(pingExtension, 1000);
```

And in your extension's content script which is allowed for this page url in manifest.json:

```
document.addEventListener("pingMyExtension", function(e) {
    console.log("ping received", e);
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("pingbackFromMyExtension", {detail: "hi, hi"}));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But this solution doesn't know whether the extension disable or not installed.......